# JSF form value disappears on submit

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, javabeans

When I try to submit a form, the input value is present in the validation-method, but gone in the submit-method. Why the input-property blank by the time the program reaches the submit-function?

Input: asdf

**genres.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText 
        id="userGenre"
        value="#{genres.input}"
        validator="#{genres.validateLength}"
        required="true" size="3"
        />
    <h:commandButton 
        value="Add genre"
        action="#{genres.submit}" 
        />
    <h:message for="userGenre" />
</h:form>
```

**Genres.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Genres {

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Genres.class);

    private String input = "";

    public void validateLength(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
        LOG.info("Validating");

        input = (String) value;
        LOG.info("name:"+input); // result: "name:asdf"

        int min = 3;
        int max = 15;
        int len = input.length();
        if (len < min || len > max) {
            ((UIInput) toValidate).setValid(false);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Must be at least 3 and at most 15 characters.");
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context), message);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void submit() {
        LOG.info("Submitting");
        LOG.info("name:"+input); // result: "name:"

        // process input
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>genres</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>no.krystah.Genres</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>input</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
        <value/>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `#{genres.submit}` when you try to submit then JSF will generate a new instance of your **Genres** class so **input** is blank but if you use **@ManagedBean** annotation on the top of your **Genres** class I think the code should work well

Comment: It would make sense, because whatever I initialize the "input" field with (in this code, I use "") is what will be sent upon submit. Adding the @ManagedBean annotation did, however, not help unfortunately..

Comment: I take that back. Adding ManagedBean alone did not work, but if I also removed @Named, it worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: you're welcome , glad to see that your problem has been solved